# Need to silently provide Windows batch file & shell script two user inputs

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I have a windows batch file as well as shell script file. When it is executed it prompts for two user inputs. I am calling these batch file or shell script from some third party software , so I want to pass two values silently so that no prompt is asked if I call and try to execute these scripts

I have tried following commands in case of windows batch file but none of them works for me:

1. `(echo val1 & cmd \c echo val2)|myBatchFile.bat`
2. `(cmd \c echo val1 & cmd \c echo val2)|myBatchFile.bat`

Comment: What is \c supposed to be? /c?

Comment: A "shell" script implies UNIX/Linux/Mac. I do not see that here. Hover the mouse pointer over the `shell` tag to see for what it is intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the values as arguments to the batch

Regards,
Leslie